# How do I load the `web3` module using the html `script` element?

Tags: web3js, nodejs

How do I load the `web3` module into the frontend of my application using the html `script` element?

I have already installed the `web3` module using `npm`. This is the path to the web3 module in my app directory.

```
../node_modules/web3/
```

I uploaded the require.js module in the following way using the script element:

```
script data-main="app" src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

What is the correct file path to use when I am attempting to upload the web3 module using the `script` element and `src` attribute? I do not know which filepath is the correct one to load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.36/dist/web3.min.js" integrity="sha256-nWBTbvxhJgjslRyuAKJHK+XcZPlCnmIAAMixz6EefVk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

you can search for a more recent version in cnd: https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/web3

Hope this helps